# How to return httpResponse result LIbGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

So I have been trying to return the content grabbed from httpResponse from a class, however, im not very successful at the moment.

```
    String requestContent = null;
    Net.HttpRequest httpRequest;
    httpRequest = new Net.HttpRequest(Net.HttpMethods.GET);
    httpRequest.setUrl("https://api.parse.com/1/classes/gamerooms/");
    System.out.println(Parse.getRestAPIKey() + Parse.getApplicationId());
    httpRequest.setHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", Parse.getApplicationId());
    httpRequest.setHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", Parse.getRestAPIKey());
    httpRequest.setContent(requestContent);

    Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(httpRequest, new Net.HttpResponseListener() {


        @Override
        public void handleHttpResponse(Net.HttpResponse httpResponse) {
            content = httpResponse.getResultAsString();
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable t) {

        }

        @Override
        public void cancelled() {

        }
    });
    return content;
}
```

When I return content, it is empty but when i print the content in handleHttpResponse, i can see it there. Any solutions?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195608/synchronous-responses-to-gdx-net-sendhttprequest-in-libgdx

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that it is handled like a Thread. So when you're returning the content, the answer maybe not already arrived. So you must handle the result in the `handleHttpResponse` method. If you don't want all the code in that method, you could also call a function.

Also because you're in a Thread I think you should call `Gdx.app.postRunnable(Runnable runnable)` if you want to change something in the code, which you shouldn't while you are in the render method or need OpenGL context. The Runnable will be called directly before the `render` method. [Threading libGdx](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Threading)

Comment: Is there anyway to return the content perhaps without using a thread? Seems impossible to me at the moment.

Comment: No one I'm aware of and I think there aren't cause the Network Request must be called in a thread otherwise the UI will freeze that time.

Comment: @NexonIsdumb You have to look at it like this: your method is being run and you assign listeners to catch the `HttpResponse` the method is not going to wait for the listener to respond that is why you can only access fields declared `final` within a listener. If you give us more information on what you are trying to achieve we could be of more help. Perhaps you could pass an object along and access a method where you pass the httpResponse into?